# Plotting Points of A Function that Satisfy Other Conditions

Tags: plotting

I want to graph this function:

```
DivisorSigma[1,x]-(x+1)
```

However, I only want to plot the points that satisfy other conditions:

```
DivisorSigma[0,x]-2=2
```

and

```
Mod[x,2]=1
```

Is that possible within Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) or [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html):

```
f[x_] = ConditionalExpression[
  DivisorSigma[1, x] - (x + 1), 
  Mod[x, 2] == 1 && DivisorSigma[0, x] - 2 == 2
];

DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, 1, 100}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This could be exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

```
{#,DivisorSigma[1,#]-(#+1)}&/@Select[Range[100],DivisorSigma[0,#]-2==2&&OddQ[#]&]
ListPlot[%]
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about the "Mod" part?

Comment: And I don't want to list the points.

Comment: Is there a way to plot multiple functions at the same time with this command

Comment: Yes. Read the documentation for `ListPlot`.